# I just have done or I have just done

Tags: adverbs, past-participles

are both of "I just have done" and "I have just done" correct? I guess the first sentence is more informal but grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

I have just done is correct.

Rather than saying ‘I just have done’ You would say ‘I just did’

Comment: do you mean "I just have done" is wrong?

Comment: @FarhangAmaji , yes, I’m pretty sure it is wrong.

Comment: "I just have done" is wrong unless you are trying to say that you have just done only some particular thing from among many you might have done. Then it's correct but awkward.

Answer (score 0):

As sentences, both are wrong because "do" is a transitive verb and takes a direct object. You have to have done *something*.

This is correct and natural:

> I **have just** done *the laundry*.

> I **just have** done *the laundry*.

This, however, is only correct if the speaker strongly stresses "JUST HAVE" to emphasizing how recently they did the laundry, in a complaining way, like a child responding to being told to do the laundry right after they did it.

If the sentence is supposed to be an answer to a question like, "Have you finished your homework?", then the answer should be:

> I just **have**.

OR

> I just **did**.